# 4003 error Lync server 2010

Tags: lync, lync-2010

My Lync 2010 Standard Edition deployment used to work, but after restoring a server because a problem, the control panel does not allow me to enable users. I get this error:

```
“Insufficient access rights to perform the operation 00002098: SecErr: DSID-03150BB9,problem 4003 (INSUFF_ACCESS_RIGHTS), data 0″.You do not have the appropriate permissions to perform this operation in Active Directory. One possible cause is that the Lync Server Control Panel and Remote Windows PowerShell cannot modify users who belong to protected security groups (for example, the Domain Admins group). To manage users in the Domain Admins group, use the Lync Server Management Shell and log on using a Domain Admins account. There are other possible causes. For details, see Lync Server 2010 Help.
```

I follwed this solution but it does not work form me: http://davesimm.blogspot.com.ar/2011/02/lync-enabling-or-making-lync-changes-to.html
Is there other way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after recieving a negative vote (I do not why), I solved the problem myself: I executed the powershell as administrator and used this command:

```
Enable-CsUser –Identity "Name and other name" –RegistrarPool poolName.domain.com –SipAddress "sip:UserCN@domain.com"
```